# How to create typealias of a function type which refers to a particular function

Tags: swift, function, types

The [official Documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-ID158) of Swift says

> You use function types just like any other types in Swift. For example, you can define a constant or variable to be of a function type and assign an appropriate function to that variable:

```
func addTwoInts(a: Int, _ b: Int) -> Int {
    return a + b
}

var mathFunction: (Int, Int) -> Int = addTwoInts
```

Here inside the sample code:

> it Define a variable called `mathFunction`, which has a type of a function that takes two `Int` values, and returns an `Int` values. Set this new variable to refer to the function called addTwoInts

**Question**: The function type can be used like any other types in Swift, I wonder, since how can I create a type alias which has a type of a function that takes two `Int` values, and returns an `Int` values. Set this new variable to refer to the function called addTwoInts

I've tried this, obviously, I was wrong.

[image]

Comment: A typealias defines a new name for a type, not a value. `typealias MyInt = Int = 17` wouldn't compile either, so that is not related to functions.

Comment: Do this instead - `typealias mathFunction = (Int, Int) -> Int` Check this for the details https://medium.com/swift-programming/swift-typealias-to-the-rescue-b1027fc571e3#.jt0iwvxa2

Comment: Thanks a lot for your guy's explanation I think I understand it better now I can do this `typealias InInOutIn = (Int, Int) -> Int`
                   `var mathFunctionII: InInOutIn = addTwoInts`

Comment: @vadian Yes, you've pointed out the point I misunderstood it. `typealias` is for types function is not a type. Thanks for your help

Comment: @vadian This might be a bad question: Why variable can have a functional type, I just feel a bit odd.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You cannot assign a function to a `typealias`.

You can only assign a type.

```
typealias mathFunctionType = (Int, Int) -> Int

let mathFunction: mathFunctionType = { int1, int2 in
    return int1 + int2
}
```